# Action listener JList and create Jtable based on Jlist selection

Tags: java, swing, jtable, listener, jlist

I have Jlist that have list of tables . I want the user to select table from the JList and this  should change the values in the JTable that being created next to JTable. However, I get exception "Exception in thread `"AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException"`

I know this exception result of the object not being created.

If I let the program read the first Table from JList it will work fine as soon as I select different value from JList and give me Exception in thread `"AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException.`

My listener is simply

```
table.setModel(New TableModel):
```

Comment: I think you need to post more of your code for people to be able to help

Comment: More of your code would be nice.  Sounds like your are not populating an array like you think you are.

Comment: Oh Sorry,  Thanks I solve it. It turned out stupid mistake I have the file read in the wrong directory and I did not make file check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was problem with directory because JTable read from files . 
here is my code for the listener if any body interested. CSVReader is AbstractTableModel that read CSV file
I don't expect answer.

```
 class SharedListSelectionHandler implements ListSelectionListener {
        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
 ListSelectionModel lsm = (ListSelectionModel)e.getSource();
if (!lsm.isSelectionEmpty()) {

CSVReader newCSV = new CSVReader((String)FileList.getSelectedValue());
               table.setModel(newCSV);


}
```